# Unable to install kubuntu-Desktop in ubuntu 16.04 Lts

Tags: kubuntu, 16.04

Following snippet is what I used to install `kubuntu-desktop` in `ubuntu-16.04 LTS`

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

Got error message,

```
kubuntu-desktop is already the newest version (1.338).
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kde-telepathy-minimal : Depends: kde-config-telepathy-accounts (>= 15.04.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Following the error message when  I tried to install using

```
apt-get install -f
```

I got the following error message,

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  kde-config-telepathy-accounts
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  kde-config-telepathy-accounts
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
680 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/137 kB of archives.
After this operation, 825 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 283314 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking kde-config-telepathy-accounts (4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service', which is also in package account-plugin-google 0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please help me resolve this.Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you might have two conflicting packages - one required by Kubuntu. That's all I can add to the issue.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -f`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I solved this issue by doing a forced overwrite

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite  /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

and then fixing the installation with

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution.  It resolved the issue for me.  This is a known bug tracked in launchpad.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ktp-accounts-kcm/+bug/1557698